# Identifies the differences between pairs of strings

Tags: c, for-loop, char, c-strings, string-comparison

I'm going to identify the difference between two string. I can't see what I'm missing here. The output from my code is correct by the sample. But when I test run it with other test, it fails. I can't see what the other tests are.

The input:

The first line of input contains an integer 1<= n <= 500, indicating the number of test cases that follow. Each test case is a pair of lines of the same length, 1 to 50 characters. Each string contains only letters (a-z,A-Z) or digits (0-9).

The Output:

For each test case, output the two lines in the order they appear in the input. Output a third line indicating similarities and differences as described above. Finally, output a blank line after each case.

Sample:

[image]

[image]

```
int main()
{
     
    int n;
    
    // scan the integer for number of test cases
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    //Loop through the test cases
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char string1[1024], string2[1024], output[50];

        //Scan first and second string
        if(scanf("%s", string1) != 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        
        if(scanf("%s", string2) != 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        //Loop through the strings and compare them
        for (int i = 0; string1[i] != '\0' || string2[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            //Convert to lowercase
            string1[i] = tolower(string1[i]);
            string2[i] = tolower(string2[i]);

            //Compare
            if (string1[i] == string2[i])
            {
                output[i] = '.';
            } else {
                output[i] = '*';
            }
            
        }

        //Print the strings and the output.
        printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", string1, string2, output);

        if(i + 1 < n) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        

    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the string1 and string2 to be 1024 bytes in size but output is only 50? Shouldn't they be the same size?

Comment: @whiplash Thats correct. I was just trying to see what the problem could be so I put them big so they was not to small.

Comment: All your character arrays should have size 51 to hold string of 50 characters.

Comment: Who told you to do case insensitive comparison?

Comment: @Gerhardh Even if I have a size of 51 or 1024 it fails.

Comment: @Gerhardh no one told me to I just tried of that was the problem but it didnt work even if I didnt change all to lowercases

Comment: But then you do not output the strings as you got them which I would consider an error. Which means your code does not pass the known test cases.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thats true. How can I check if a 'A' == 'a'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248179/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-inomie).

Comment: I found the problem. It dont want it to be the same between 'A' and 'a'. So that was one problem and the missing '\0' was the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that when you have an input string in upper case ("ABCD") you print it in lowercase in the output ("abcd")?

Comment: Thats true it can be that they dont see it as the same

Answer (score 1):

The output string is never terminated, a '\0' should be added after the loop is over, otherwise printf would read over to the memory filled by previous test cases if their inputs were longer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no great sense to declare the variable n as having the signed integer type `int`. Declare it at least as having type `unsigned int`.

```
unsigned int n;

// scan the integer for number of test cases
if(scanf("%u", &n) != 1) {
    return 1;
}
```

The three character array should be declared as having 51 elements

```
char string1[51], string2[51], output[51];
```

The calls of scanf will look like

```
    //Scan first and second string
    if(scanf(" %50s", string1) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    if(scanf(" %50s", string2) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }
```

Also you need to check that the entered strings have the same length as for example

```
    if( strlen( string1) != strlen( string2 ) ) {
        return 1;
    }
```

This for loop

```
   for (int i = 0; string1[i] != '\0' || string2[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

can invoke undefined behavior if the lengths of strings are not equal each other. If you will include the above shown if statement then the for loop can look the following way

```
size_t i = 0;
for ( ; string1[i] != '\0'; i++ )
```

These statements change the original strings

```
//Convert to lowercase
string1[i] = tolower(string1[i]);
string2[i] = tolower(string2[i]);
```

that you should not do. Just compare corresponding characters like

```
if (string1[i] == string2[i])
{
    output[i] = '.';
} else {
    output[i] = '*';
}
```

If you want to compare characters independent on their cases then write

```
if ( tolower( ( unsigned char )string1[i] ) == tolower( ( unsigned char )string2[i] ) )
{
    output[i] = '.';
} else {
    output[i] = '*';
}
```

After the for loop write

```
output[i] = '\0';
```

tp form a string in the array `output`.

It seems this if statement

```
if(i + 1 < n) {
    printf("\n");
}
```

is redundant. Just output the new line character `'\n'`

```
putchar( '\n' );
```

after each test case.

Comment: why do you want to use the unsigned int instead of just int in this case?

Comment: @Inomie Because there is no any sense to use a signed integer type when the valid range of values is not negative. Otherwise it will only confuse users.

Answer (score 0):

Needlessly complicated. And, if the source strings contain any whitespace characters, `scanf` won't satisfy your needs. Below is both simpler and more robust.

Challenge assures no line more than 50 (or 500???) chars, so use only two small arrays.
Challenge is to also output LF after EVERY test case, so suppressing final one with special code is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void readAline( char *p, size_t n ) { // do or die
    if( fgets( p, n, stdin ) == NULL )
        exit( 1 );
}

int mmain() {
    char buf[2][ 50 + 1 + 1 ]; // +2 = up to 50 + LF + '\0' from fgets()

    readAline( buf[0], sizeof buf[0] );
    int n = atoi( buf[0] );

    while( n-- ) {
        readAline( buf[0], sizeof buf[0] );
        readAline( buf[1], sizeof buf[1] );

        // can't be too careful when dealing with input
        assert( strlen( buf[0] ) == strlen( buf[ 1 ] ) );

        printf( "%s%s", buf[0], buf[1] ); // echo to stdout

        // source data defined "up to 50 chars, so no test for '\0'
        // recycle buf[0] for output
        for( int i = 0; buf[0][i] != '\n'; i++ )
            buf[0][i] = buf[0][i] == buf[1][i] ? '.' : '*';

        puts( buf[0] ); // uses loaded LF and appended LF
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Demonstration

```
1
the cat sat on the mat
the fat cat in the vat
the cat sat on the mat // here is the echo
the fat cat in the vat
....*...*...*......*.. // here is the analysis
// blank line
```